# NextJS Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components when passing a higher-order function to form action

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js14

I'm studying the official dashboard tutorial of NextJS and this part (along with the `updateInvoice` part) got me curious:

https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/mutating-data#deleting-an-invoice

I played with two approaches to passing the `deleteInvoice` function to the form action, one with the `bind` method (the one used in the tutorial) and another with a higher-order function that wraps `deleteInvoice`.

The `bind` version worked perfectly:

```
const deleteInvoiceWithId = deleteInvoice.bind(null, id)
return (
    <form action={deleteInvoiceWithId}>
     // other code
    </form>
);
```

While the higher-order function version :

```
const deleteInvoiceWithId = async () => deleteInvoice(id)
return (
    <form action={deleteInvoiceWithId}>
     // other code
    </form>
);
```

threw Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".

My question is, I'm obviously creating and passing a new function to the form action in either case, but why does the `bind` case work while the higher-order function version fail? What is the **fundamental difference** between the 2 approaches?